# Handle tel:// links in WKWebView on iPad

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm trying to handle clicks on "tel:xxxxx" links in WKWebView. The code below works on iPhone, but on an iPad the callback `webView(_ webView:,decidePolicyFor:,decisionHandler:)` is not called. Is there any workaround?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><a href=\"tel:4085551212\">Click here to call</a></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
    }
    
    // MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
            print("navigation to url: \(url)")
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

}
```